# Split window java script for InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Does anyone know of or can help me figure out how to create a script for InDesign to do the Split Screen command, this is found under menu selection Window > Arrange > Split Window. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically this should work:

```
app.menuActions.item("$ID/Split Window").invoke()
```

But actually it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I can't tell why.

It works more or less stable as a toggle split/unsplit this way:

```
try {
    app.menuActions.item("$ID/Split Window").invoke()
} catch(e) {
    app.menuActions.item("$ID/Unsplit Window").invoke()
}
```

Probably there is some property, which you can read and run split command only if the window is not splitted already. I don't know.

**Update**

The list of 'menuActions' you can get with this script:

```
var list = "ID\tName\tArea\n";
var i = 0;

for (var i=0; i<app.menuActions.length; i++) {
    var m = app.menuActions[i];
    list += m.id + "\t" + m.name + "\t" + m.area + "\n";
}

f = File("menu_actions.txt");
f.encoding = "UTF-8";
f.open("w");
f.write(list);
f.close();

f.execute(); // to open the txt file immediately

\\ alert(i + " actions wese saved to " + f.fsName);
```

All credits to Kasyan Servetsky: http://kasyan.ho.ua/tips/indesign_script/all/open_menu_item.html

Comment: Yuri, you are amazing, this is awesome! Thank you so much! Forgive me for the question, but how do you know what are the IDs to invoke in the parenthesis for the menuAction ?

Comment: Again, thank you Yuri, this is just awesome!

Comment: As for your question about resizing image by document size in InDesign, you need to describe more thoroughly the workflow: how the image gets into document, how the script detects what the image is need to resize (can doc has many images?), how to resize an image in case its proportions doesn't fit with document proportions, if doc has one page or several, etc.